# NetLogo-Mathematica Link NLGetPatches won't work

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, netlogo

I'm using NetLogo 6.0.2 and the NetLogo-Mathematica Link to try to capture "screenshots" of the NetLogo world (as described in the NetLogo-Mathematica Link Tutorial document).  The NLGetPatches command doesn't seem to work at all.  I tried a workaround with a simple test case...  I setup the NetLogo world (41x41) with a single yellow patch at (10,0), and used the following code in Mathematica:

`colors = NLReport["[pcolor] of patches"];
gridcolors = Partition[colors, 41];
ArrayPlot[gridcolors, ColorRules->{0.->Black,45.->Yellow}]`

It produces the world, but with the yellow patch located in a different position.  It seems to have shuffled the patches. Does NLReport query the patches in a random order?  If so, how can I report them left-to-right, top-to-bottom instead?

Thanks for the help!  Here's the code that replaces the above and works:

`colors = NLReport["map[? -> [pcolor] of ?] sort patches"];
gridcolors = Partition[colors, 41];
ArrayPlot[gridcolors, ColorRules->{0.->Black,45.->Yellow}]`

Comment: Not familiar with Mathematica, but the Netlogo command itself `[pcolor] of patches` will query the patches in random order.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the normal sort order of patches, so

```
map [? -> [pcolor] of ?]] sort patches
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've edited my original question with  the working code.

Comment: @capelian  I believe you added extra quotes.  Also:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers